# Can my PC run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-requirements

My computer's specs are:
System: Microsoft Windows XP
        Professional
        Version 2002
        Service Pack 3

Computer:
        Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU
        E7500 @ 2.93 GHz
        2.93 GHz, 1.99 Gb of RAM

If my computer can't run the current version of Ubuntu, are there older versions of Ubuntu can run on this PC?

Comment: Yes.  Should be fine.

Comment: It would be good if you could include the graphics card information as well. My 2c is that it should run well. If it is running slow you could try the linux mint 15 mate edition. It's based on ubuntu but is a bit faster

Answer (score 2):

That spec. is fine to run **32-bit** Ubuntu.

I would recommend: **12.04.2 LTS**

[Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

You should 'try' first, with a USB or DVD start disk.

---

To be certain of full support, you also need to identify the graphics chip/card, and any other (unusual) devices or applications ..

Answer (score 0):

That should be able to run Ubuntu 13.04.  But if it doesn't, use one of the LTS releases.  Like 10.04 (old, but works) or 12.04.  They are very stable and are more likely to work.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is fine... Ubuntu works fine on my laptop too with only 512 mb or RAM and 1.6 GHZ of CPU power. So your computer should be fine. Try it from a live USB. Base on your specs, you may able to run Ubuntu 13.04 well. Otherwise, use 12.04 like me.

---

Note, my PC does not have opengl 2.0 too. Unity still works well but slow.